# DateTime format in the TITLE of the <apex:column>

Tags: apex, visualforce, mousehover

On a Visualforce page, I am displaying **CreatedDate** field as a title for one of the `<apex: column>`. This gives me the ability to get the time of record creation when the mouse hovers.

Apex controller:

```
..
public DateTime CreatedDateHover{get;set;}
..
for(Object__c var: mapdata.Values()){
      ..
      rec.CreatedDateHover = var.CreatedDate;
      ..
}
..
```

Visualforce page:

```
<apex:column title="{!a.CreatedDateHover}" headerValue="Entity">
        <apex:outputLink value="/{!a.Id}"> {!a.Field} </apex:outputLink>
</apex:column>
```

The format I get when I hover my mouse:

> Fri Sep 08 16:29:22 GMT 2017

How can I change this format to something like:

> Fri Sep 08 2017, 04:29:22 Pm

How can I have the time format to 12 hour clock with AM/PM changes based on it? Is there a way to get the timezone based on the Org's timezone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use apex:outputext and adjust the format as needed:

[Visualforce Date formatting](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/22321/visualforce-date-formatting)

Dateformat reference: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

```
<apex:outputLink value="/{!account.Id}"> 
    <apex:outputText value="{0,date,EE MM dd yyyy, hh:mm:ss aaa}">
        <apex:param value="{!account.createddate}" /> 
    </apex:outputText>
</apex:outputLink>
```

**Update**: Another Simple idea you can try is to use a tooltip : 
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp
I literally copy pasted the style from the tooltip CSS and adjusted the VF page as below:

```
 <apex:column >
                 <div class="tooltip">
                   <apex:outputLink value="/{!account.Id}"> {!account.createddate} </apex:outputLink>
                    <span class="tooltiptext">
                        <apex:outputText value="{0,date,EE MM dd yyyy, hh:mm:ss aaa}" styleClass="tooltip">
                            <apex:param value="{!account.createddate}" /> 
                        </apex:outputText>
                    </span>
                </div>
        </apex:column>
```

Output:
[image]

Full VF page with style class included incase you want to modify it:

```
<apex:page standardController="account">
<style>
.tooltip {
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 190px;
    background-color: black;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 5px 0;

    /* Position the tooltip */
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
    visibility: visible;
}
</style>
   <apex:pageblock >
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Account}" var="account">
        <apex:column >
                 <div class="tooltip">
                   <apex:outputLink value="/{!account.Id}"> {!account.createddate} </apex:outputLink>
                    <span class="tooltiptext">
                        <apex:outputText value="{0,date,EE MM DD YYYY, hh:mm:ss aaa}" styleClass="tooltip">
                            <apex:param value="{!account.createddate}" /> 
                        </apex:outputText>
                    </span>
                </div>
        </apex:column>  
    </apex:pageBlockTable>



    </apex:pageblock>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Updated answer seems promising, I will try to implement it and get back to you. Thanks :)

Comment: Man, you are the best! I owe you a beer. Let me know when you plan to visit DC.

Comment: I see the time is not formatted well. Do you know why? I am getting this: `Fri 09 251 2017, 11:29:52 AM` which doesn't make sense to me. This is the actual creation date: `9/8/2017 7:29 AM` (local time, EST)

Comment: what is the value of the outputtext you are using? I am getting it as expected using {0,date,EE MM DD YYYY, hh:mm:ss aaa}

Comment: I am using the one you posted in your answer. You can check with a record that was created this month which would have 251 number or something similar. Also how to get the company's timezone for the timestamp?

Comment: my bad JS is case sensitive, it should be {0,date,EE MM dd yyyy, hh:mm:ss aaa} I had DD, YYYY in the original post

Comment: Fixed the issue with the timezone. On the force.com, the timezone is always set to GMT. To make it EST, I need to append some fraction at the end of the  data binding: `{!a.CreatedDateHover-1/6}`. Referenced this: [Answer from Chirag Mehta](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/28765/created-date-time-difference). Hope someone finds this helpful.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a header facet.

```
<apex:column>
    <apex:facet name="header">
        <!-- fancy stuff here (like formatted outputText tag) -->
    </apex:facet>
</apex:column>
```

Comment: I would like to display the timestamp as the mouse-hover text for this apex:column? How can I get that?